# Can not update entries with many to many relation in Flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am totally new with flask and sqlalchemy. I try to make one web site just to get better understanding of flask. I have something like blog where user can create post and set multiple tags. I use flask-sqlalchemy and wtforms-alchemy. I have 2 models

```
association_table = db.Table('association',
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    categories = db.relationship('Category', secondary=association_table,
                            backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

    ...
class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    ...
```

I can create new post with next view

```
def add():
    form = PostForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        post = Post(form.title.data, form.body.data)
        db.session.add(post)
        tags = form.tags.data.split(',')
        for tag in tags:
            category = Category.query.filter_by(name=tag.strip()).first()
            if not category:
                category = Category(tag.strip())
            post.categories.append(category)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(...)
    return render_template(...)
```

That works as it should. But I have a couple of problems with editing of posts. When I change title or body I have to use db.session.merge(post) otherwise it does not want to save changes in database. But in all tutorials there are no that merge method.
Second problem is that I can not update tags of the post. I can create a new tag and add it to some post. But if I try to add existing tag to any post I have an error.

```
AssertionError: A conflicting state is already present in the identity map for key (<class 'db.models.Category'>, (1,))
```

my view looks like

```
def edit(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get(post_id)
    form = PostForm(request.form, post)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

        ...

        tags = form.tags.data.split(',')
        for tag in tags:
            category = Category.query.filter_by(name=tag.strip()).first()
            if not category:
                category = Category(tag.strip())
            db.session.remove()
            post.categories.append(category)
        form.populate_obj(post)
        db.session.merge(post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(...)
    else:
        ...

    return render_template(...)
```

Also if I do not use db.session.remove() I will get another error

```
InvalidRequestError: Object '<Category at 0x7f9de40c0d90>' is already attached to session '6' (this is '1')
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks for any help!

One update. Just for tests. If I iterate list of tags from one post I can remove those tags and append it back.

```
tags = list(post.categories)
for tag in tags:
    post.categories.remove(tag)

for tag in tags:
    post.categories.append(tag)
```

But if I remove tags then get tag from db and try to append - got an error

```
tags = list(post.categories)
for tag in tags:
    post.categories.remove(tag)

for tag in tags:
    category = Category.query.filter_by(name=tag.name).first()
    post.categories.append(tag) 


AssertionError: A conflicting state is already present in the identity map for key (<class 'db.models.Category'>, (1,))
```

I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I use WooshAlchemy for text-search. And it creates different sessions. Big article about that can be found [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling)

Comment: Yes, this is a problem when using flask_whooshalchemy library. The patch by Miguel Grinberg (the link in the answer above) was finally merged to the github repository of the library. But it hasn't been released yet to pip as of May 2014. If you need to get past this error, you'd need to apply the patch manually to the flask_whooshalchemy.py.

Answer (score 3):

Why that

```
db.session.remove()
```

in your code?

Quick rule of thumb with `sqlalchemy`:

Only when you create a new instance, you have to add it to the session.
Everything returned by a query (also valid for the relationships) is already in the session so you don't need to add or remove anything.

So to add a new category you simply

- create the object
- add to the session
- append to the `categories` list
- `db.session.commit`

To modify a category

- modify the desired `categories` entry
- `db.session.commit`

To delete an association

- delete from the `categories` list
- `db.session.commit`

To delete **a category object** you need to also

- `db.session.delete(cat)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I told above without db.session.remove() I have another error InvalidRequestError. I can create new posts, new categories, edit another fields of post but can not append existing category to any existing post. I guess that problem somewhere deeper in the code and not only in the part I posted